# Typescript promise in Svelte

Tags: typescript, svelte

I am new to using Typescript (and Svelte). I converted a small example I made with javascript to typescript and get an error when I use the value from the returned promise.

The `<p>The foo value is {foo}</p>` renders to `The foo value is [object Object]`, but if I include `{foo.Count}` then I get a runtime error that I can't access `Count` on an undefined variable.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  interface Metrics {
    Count: number;
  }

  async function getMetrics(serverIP: string): Promise<Metrics> {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
    const posts: any[] = await res.json();

    if (res.ok) {
      let metrics: Metrics = { Count: posts.length };
      return metrics;
    } else {
      throw new Error(res.statusText);
    }
  }

  let metrics: Promise<Metrics>;

  onMount(() => {
    metrics = getMetrics("abc");
  });
</script>

<main>
  {#await metrics}
    <p>waiting for the promise to resolve...</p>
  {:then foo}
    {@debug foo}
    <p>The foo value is {foo}</p>
    <p>The name is {foo.Count}</p>
  {:catch error}
    <p>Something went wrong: {error.message}</p>
  {/await}

</main>
```

Adding `<code>{JSON.stringify(foo)}</code>` outputs `{"Count": 100}` as expected.

The error I get with `{foo.Count}` is

`[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ctx[1].Count') (anonymous function) (proxy.js:385) Module Code (main.ts:3)`

Comment: How about this: `onMount(async () => { metrics = await getMetrics("abc"); });`. Using `async/await` with `onMount` callback.

Comment: Imho not TS related - reproducible on svelte.dev in plain JS.

Comment: Also, check console output - there are 2 entries, in the first one (before the onMount is called) foo is indeed undefined

Comment: Initializing metrics to a real promise `let metrics = new Promise(() => {});` solves the issue.

Comment: @NalinRanjan Thanks; yesterday I spent a bunch of time on that. Typescript would complain that "Type 'Metrics' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<Metrics>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]" when I did that.

Comment: @Lesiak nice, you are a genius! It worked when I did that, but with a typescript warning, but it helped me get to `let metrics: Promise<Metrics> = new Promise(() => {});` which works and don't have any TS warnings.  (And VS Code can autocomplete {foo.Count} in the template. Thanks so much for the help & answer.

Comment: @Lesiak: Please post an actual answer so it can be accepted as well.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments:

The problem is not TS specific, it can be reproduced on svelte.dev in plain JS.

The problem stems from the fact that [await blocks](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks) enter their then branch if the awaited value is not a promise.

In your case the awaited value is undefined - you only initialize the promise in the onMount. To observe this, add a log in onMount.

I can see the following in the console:

- foo: undefined
- onMount entered
- foo: "Count": 100

Solution ideas:

- don't use onMount at all, fire the request before the component is mounted
- use a unresolved promise as initial value of metrics variable. Await block only observes the last value of the variable.
- use a loading router